# Insert table with headers and single row from activecell in outlook mail

Tags: excel, vba, datatable, outlook

I want to include the headers from the excel sheet I am working in together with the current row for which name i am on into each outlook mail i am creating.
I have tried different things such as including xlToRight as a range and inserting that every Next Name.

I hope someone has a easy solution that i have missed.

```
Sub PLGBarcodeFile()

Dim EApp As Object
Set EApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim EItem As Object

Dim path As String
'path =

Dim NameList As Range
Set NameList = Range("A2", Range("a2").End(xlDown))

Dim Name As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

For Each Name In NameList

Set EItem = EApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    With EItem
        .To = Name.Offset(0, 8)
        .Subject = "Evaluate information regarding barcodes for " & Name.Offset(0, 1)
        '.Attachments.Add path
        .Body = "Dear " & Name.Offset(0, 9) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
        & "Standard Text" & vbNewLine _
        & "Standard Text" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
        & "Standard Text" & vbNewLine _
        & "PStandard Text" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
        & "Standard Text" & vbNewLine _
        & "Standard Text" & vbNewLine _
        & "Standard Text" & vbNewLine _
        & "Standard Text" & vbNewLine _
        & "Standard Text" & Name.Offset(0, 1) & vbNewLine _
        & "INSERT TABLE HERE" & vbNewLine _
        & "Standard Text" & vbNewLine _
        & "Standard Text" & vbNewLine _
        & "Standard Text" & vbNewLine _
        & "Standard Text"
         
        .Display
         
    End With
    
Next Name

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Body` property doesn't include any formatting, it is a plain text string. Instead, you may consider using the copy and paste methods. The Outlook object model supports three main ways of customizing the message body:

1. The [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-body-property-outlook) property returns or sets a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. The [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-htmlbody-property-outlook) property of the `MailItem` class returns or sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. Setting the `HTMLBody` property will always update the `Body` property immediately.
3. The Word object model can be used for dealing with message bodies. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) for more information. So, you can use the copy and paste methods available in Excel and Word to copy the required information including formatting.